# Two independent Excel IF logic statements in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns of data. One contains a **DataType** field that describes the data like "City", "Name" or "Zip". The next column is the **DataText** like "John Doe", "100 Main St" or "12345". The final column contains a **DataScore** is percent like ".943" or ".109".

I am trying to validate the data in two ways:

First, I want to make sure that the **DataText** matches what kind of text should be find in each **DataType**. IE City must contain numbers and letters, Zip Codes must be within a range and Name must contain only letter. I have a formula that prints "Fm.", for Format Met, if the criteria is met. Here it is:

```
=IF(H2="Month",IF(AND(N2<13,N2>1),"Fm.",""),IF(H2="Zip",IF(AND(N2>39000,N2<50000),"Fm.",""),IF(H2="Day",IF(AND(N2>0,N2<32),"Fm.",""),IF(H2="Year",IF(AND(N2=2020),"Fm.",""),IF(H2="City",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(N2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(N2))),1),"abcdefghijklmnop qrstuvwxyz.")))),"Fm.","")),IF(H2="Name",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(N2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(N2))),1),"abcdefghijklmnop qrstuvwxyz.")))),"Fm.","")),IF(H2="County",(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(N2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(N2))),1),"abcdefghijklmnop qrstuvwxyz.")))),"Fm.","")),IF(H2="Address",IF(AND(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},N2))>0,NOT(ISNUMBER(N2))),"Fm.",""),""))))))))
```

Second, I am trying to make sure the score is above a certain percent. I do this with a simple code and print "Pm.", for Percent Met, if the score is high enough. Here is the code:

```
=IF(O2>0.973,"Pm.","")
```

How can I combine both my formulas so "Fm.Pm" is printed if both the criteria is met or just one or another, "Fm." or "Pm." if one is met?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: concatenate them together with concatenate() or use the & which also does concatenate with less typing.

Comment: That is just what I needed. I had no idea Concatenate could be used like that. Thank you!

Comment: Note that you don't need Concatenate(). It only adds yet another pair of brackets to an already overly complex formula. Just use the `&` sign between the two formulas.